# Manipulação Imagens JavaScript

Tags: javascript, imagem

Alguém conhece alguma biblioteca para manipulação de imagens em JavaScript?
Queria juntar duas imagens em uma, em determinadas posições pré-fixadas.
Um exemplo são aqueles testes para facebook, que pega a imagem do perfil de uma determinada pessoa e adicionada em outra imagem de fundo.

Answer (score 0):

Este exemplo no jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sqJtr/ creio que pode lhe ajudar, coloca uma imagem sobre outra com "div" mas pode mudar para "img" que vai funcionar também.

Comment: Mas no caso eu precisava manipular duas imagens ou mais para criar uma outra, não só colocar uma encima da outra.
Como se fosse automatizar um processo que poderia fazer com o Photoshop, Firework...